# ERROR: Expected to not be in Angular Zone, but it is

Tags: angular, zone, micro-frontend

I was trying to build a demo by using Angular and single-spa to see whether this could be our future path of development. Here is the example I tried to borrow from.

https://github.com/PlaceMe-SAS/single-spa-angular-cli-examples

However, I found when routing to another application, for example: click on Open Help or App1, the console will have errors like "ERROR: Expected to not be in Angular Zone, but it is!"

I did some research on internet trying to fix this error. However, I didn't found solution. I also submited an issue to the project. I'm just wondering whether anyone knows anything about this error here.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Did you use the router to change page? Try using `window.location.href` instead

Comment: Thank you Cristina! I tried your suggestion to change to window.location.href, it doesn't solve the issue. I think the problem is zone is double called somewhere when rounting to Open Help or App1

Comment: The problem is probably gived by the fact that you never go out from Angular zone, so when you change your application, a new Angular app bootstraps and it tries to start a new zone. Then it notices it's already in a zone and throws an error. You can use `this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => window.location ....)`, but this is just a workaround

Comment: Another problem could be that your applications aren't siblings, but there is an angular app inside an angular app. I should check your code to say this, I'm gonna clone it later

Comment: Please let me know when you clone it. I believe I tried the "this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => window.location ....)" already and it didn't work for me. Thanks Cristina!

Comment: Any other solution for this error? I tried the solution provided, but none seems to be working. I am getting this error on the Production server but not on local or any test server. What might be causing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to post our solution here. One of our developers solved this zone error by calling zone in each index.html. So in the portal main.js, remove the zone import and call zone from index.html

index.html

```
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.8.19/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/build/common.js"></script>
    <script src="/build/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Issue still exists. Any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Check for multiple bootstrap components.
I was trying to call a micro frontend (mfe) when this error showed up. All I did was to remove the bootstrap attribute from the entry module of the mfe.

```
// (this is a micro front end module)
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  bootstrap: [DashboardComponent], // <= remove this
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DashboardUiModule,
// rest omitted
```

the bootstrap component here tries to start Angular Zone.js, but as the parent/shell app is already running, it throws this error.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!